# Bitwise OR doing more than expected

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I'm programming a simple module which requires the use of Bitwise OR. My plan is to "Bitwise ORing" four numbers:

- 0x00000004
- 0x00000010
- 0x00000040
- 0x80000000

I outputed them on the console, to visualize them in binary instead of hex:

```
0x00000004.toString(2)
"100"
0x00000010.toString(2)
"10000"
0x00000040.toString(2)
"1000000"
0x80000000.toString(2)
"10000000000000000000000000000000"
```

So far so good. If I use the Bitwise OR operator on all of them together I reiceive a pretty weird result:

```
0x00000004 | 0x00000010 | 0x00000040 | 0x80000000
-2147483564
```

Respectively in binary:

```
(0x00000004 | 0x00000010 | 0x00000040 | 0x80000000).toString(2)
"-1111111111111111111111110101100"
```

This seems plain **wrong** to me, because I actually expected this:

```
  00000000000000000000000000000100
| 00000000000000000000000000010000
| 00000000000000000000000001000000
| 10000000000000000000000000000000
= 10000000000000000000000001010100
```

Respectively in decimal:

```
parseInt('10000000000000000000000001010100', 2)
2147483732
```

or in Hex:

```
(2147483732).toString(16)
"80000054"
```

Is there a limitation I didn't know about? (I actually *did* look up the [reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR)) Or is this a bug? Or do I misunderstand the use of Bitwise OR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, [`|`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10) and other bit operations except [`>>>`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.3) execute [`ToInt32`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5) before operate. So, `0x80000000` was converted to -2147483648. You can verify this by `0x80000000 | 0`.

If you want the result represented as a positive number. You can `>>> 0` which will call [`ToUint32`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6).

```
(0x00000004 | 0x00000010 | 0x00000040 | 0x80000000) >>> 0 // 2147483732
((0x00000004 | 0x00000010 | 0x00000040 | 0x80000000) >>> 0).toString(2) // '10000000000000000000000001010100'
```